# Office 365 oAuth verify user is member of organization

Tags: oauth, active-directory, office365, office365api

I am building a web application for a client and logging in with Office 365 is a requirement for the client. I am having a difficult time deciphering what exactly I need to do to make it so that only users with an email address belonging to their Office 365 organization can authenticate with my app using oAuth.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I going to have to implement the AD 1.0 endpoints? Being able to pull the users' groups and other enterprise-related data would be great but for simplicity's sake, all I really need to do is verify that they are apart of an organization.

How would I do this using the AD 2.0 endpoints?

Comment: Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741942/validate-organization-email-extension-using-ms-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tenant id (`tid`) claim in the identity token would identify which organization (tenant) they belong to. But even easier than just checking the `tid` for every user would be to use the tenant-specific logon URL. So instead of the `/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint, use `/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!