# Validate organization email extension using MS Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

In my application, I have a list of users with their organization email-id. As per the requirement, I want to check user's email-id extension is of a valid Microsoft 365 account. For users who passed this check, I want to enable the SSO feature.

Example: If the user email-id is "user@company-domain.com" then I want to check that "@company-domain.com" is registered in MS 365.

I am not able to find any graph API to resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be able to use is the Organizations endpoint eg

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

then use the verified domains node

```
    "verifiedDomains": [
    {
        "capabilities": "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline",
        "isDefault": true,
        "isInitial": true,
        "name": "Contoso.com",
        "type": "Managed"
    }
```

This is what you see in the Portal or enumerated in things like Azure AD Connect

This will give you the verified domains for a particular org and your app will need permissions to query it.

Comment: API requires Org Id. We only have a list of corporate domains and that too doesn't exist in our Azure AD. We want to check all corporate domains are valid and exist in MS 365.

Comment: You can use Oidc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc to sort of do that eg a Invoke-RestMethod -method get https://login.microsoftonline.com/domaintolookup.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration . In the Graph you can check all the domains that you own that are registered with Microsoft for the Org of the account your using. What you can't do is check any domain of any customer because that would be a privacy issue for Microsoft (as a service provider I can see the need to do it but the hosting party couldn't do it for security reasons) .

Comment: If not the domain, can we check if the customer's email-id a valid MS 365 account?

Comment: You could try the autodiscover services like Autodiiscover https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2018/05/22/get-autodv2/ or Autodetect https://c7solutions.com/2021/05/outlook-autodetect-and-broken-autodiscover they are meant to be used for discovering the correct mail setting for an Email address but could probably be repurposed to do what you need.

Comment: I found this API https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.json?Email=<emailId>&Protocol=rest. It works. Looks like it is O365 API. I heard that O365 is soon going to be replaced by MS365. I don't see a similar API in MS Graph.

Comment: Yeah i heard similar but the old domain will still work for a long time because they can't switch that stuff off without breaking all the apps that have hardcode the name. That don't have that in the Graph, there used to be a discover API but that's been deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/discovery-service-rest-operations. National and government tenants are also another complication